# How to restrict updating file_field if already have value in edit form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my edit form I have six file_fields for uploading images with carrier wave, they were not populated with previous images, if forgot to select images again in edit form, they were updating with nil values.

```
<%= f.fields_for :gallery, @gallery do |gf| %>
          <div class="gallery-uploads">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img1 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img1, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img2 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img2, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img3 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img3, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img4 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img4, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img5 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img5, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= gf.label :img6 %>
                <%= gf.file_field :img6, {class: 'form-control'} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

In controller update action as follows

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to product_path
  end
end
```

how to keep the previous images if they were already uploading in edit form(in update)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try setting the value on the `file_field`. If that does not work you can use a `hidden_field`.